# Installing and running Subversion

Tags: svn, installation

I installed the setup wizard for subversion "Setup-Subversion-1.7.5" But how do I run Subversion? After the installation is complete I do not see any program to run in any directory. The ReadMe file does not help me either.

Basically, what do I do after the installer is done running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the subversion manual its a really great [book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) that explains everything.

You can download it for free or search it online. They offer multiple formats. Its even available in different languages.

You usually start with [creating a repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html). Make sure you planned it before.

If you already have a repository you can start [checking something out](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command prompt to work with SVN once you have it on your system. If you want a user interface, download TortoiseSVN which is a shell extension, so keep this in mind when using it, i.e. right click any folder and you will have a TortoiseSVN menu which is called the repo browser ( i think) open that and it will display the UI.

Alternatively if you work within eclipse there are a range of plug-ins you can use. Subversive and Subclipse are two well known plug-ins.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks! I really like the idea of Subversive and Subclipse! Which would you recommend and why?

Comment: I've used subversive extensively, and I haven't had any major issues with it. The thing is, that Subversive has been developed by Eclipse team while Subclipse has been developed by the SVN team. In my opinion they are both very similar and work great even though I have only used Subclipse for a short period of time. I've heard from colleagues that subversive is more 'smooth' and works well in eclipse, but I can't confirm this fully. I recommend doing a quick Subversive vs Subclipse google search to get more views on it.

Hope you find what you're looking for.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus You didn't mention in your original post that you plan to use eclipse. We are using subversive here as well. We installed subclipse some time ago and didn't recognize any major differences. The icons and labels where a little bit different, but everything important worked.

Answer (score 0):

It was integrated into Windows Explorer, so you should see new menu items in its context menu.

But to use it like a pro, you should read this http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ book